# Product Save from admin it's adding double html URL in table url_rewrite

Tags: magento-2.0

On Product Save from Catalog Admin section, it's adding double .html in URL in table url_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

We fixed the URL's Suffix Issue like this:

---

By turning off **Create Permanent Redirect URLs** to NO in System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization and once again try to save product.

If still not works then follow below steps :

1. Remove all product related rewrites from url_rewrite table
   DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'product';
2. Mass update all products in admin to do so :
   (Select all Products,Select Update Attribute from Mass Action Dropdown,Select Website,Check the box underneath 'Add product to website' and click on Save)
3. Clear Cache
   The URLs will also be regenerated then.
   From now the URLs are correctly generated at each save of a product or category.